# Unable to get expo push notification token after generated release build in Android

Tags: android, react-native, expo, expo-notifications

I integrated expo notification for Push notification. My project is Expo bare flow

```
let token;

        const { status: existingStatus } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
        let finalStatus = existingStatus;
        if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
            const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
            finalStatus = status;
        }
        if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
            alert('Failed to get push token for push notification!');
            return;
        }

        token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync(experienceId));
        console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>token",token)
```

this is my code to get token. It perfectly works on IOS but in Android, it will work in Development. When I get the Release build with android studio, I cannot receive the token in the release build.

if i add any native based library in my project like react-native-firebase etc am not able to use that Library with native modules in my project.

while trying to run the app with the comment `react-native run-android` app will be launched but suddenly App crashed with an error. error is given below.
[image]

How can I get an expo notification token in release build android and how to fix the configured expo-updates issue.

```
   "native-base": "^2.13.5",
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-dom": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "^0.65.1",
"expo-updates": "^0.8.5",
"expo-notifications": "~0.12.3",
"expo-permissions": "~12.1.1",
"expo": "~42.0.1",
```